# Java/Scala interactive CLI with no new line on enter

Tags: java, scala, command-line-interface, jline3

I want to create a CLI that takes input commands like bash, but it's displaying content on the rest of the terminal so it must **not roll all the lines up when enter is pressed**. It should just erase the command line instead.

I'm trying [JLine3](https://github.com/jline/jline3). The `enterRawMode` stops new lines but also stops command buffering, editing, etc.

Tried `LineReader`on top of "raw mode" but it brings new lines again.

Tried playing with [stty flags](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/utilities/stty.html) but can't find one to stop new lines specifically.

Answer (score -1):

I haven't used JLine, but you could also check out [Lanterna](https://github.com/mabe02/lanterna). It gives you a lot of control over the terminal. You might have luck with either its [`Terminal`](https://github.com/mabe02/lanterna/blob/master/docs/using-terminal.md) or [`Screen`](https://github.com/mabe02/lanterna/blob/master/docs/using-screen.md) APIs.